# How to do a looping select union in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to do select from Table2 for each row in an initial select statement from Table1.

Initial `select` statement would look something like

`Select * from Table1 Where GroupID='someId' AND ObjectID='someID'`

Table1 would return something like the following (there will only ever be 0-1 returned rows with a null EndDate value).

[image]

Table2 will look as follows

[image]

Basically my goal is to loop through the first select statements rows. For each row I want to take the *objectid*, *startdate*, and *enddate* to select all the appropriate rows in Table2. Then after do a UNION(?) on all the data I've selected from Table2. I want to be able to select all the rows in Table2 which's objectid matches the objectid given and the timestamp is in-between the start/end dates (or to current timestamp if enddate is null). Does that make sense? I've been looking online, but have not found a way to achieve a looping select union like this.

I'm not sure if this is possible in a single select statement or if a stored proc is needed/cleaner (either is fine but I'd rather avoid stored proc if I can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a join:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.objectid = t2.objectid 
AND t2.timestamp BETWEEN t1.startdate AND COALESCE(t1.enddate, current_timestamp)
WHERE t1.GroupID = 'someId' AND t1.ObjectID = 'someID'
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you! Wasn't aware of the COALESCE function so thank you for that as well.